# "TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Overload resolution failed." error while using Tensorflow in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a webcam component using a Tensorflow in this component to draw a Face Landmark mesh on the detecting video image.
The code for the component is shown below:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import * as faceLandmarksDetection from "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection";

import { drawMesh } from "./utilities";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const inputResolution = {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
};

const videoConstraints = {
  width: inputResolution.width,
  height: inputResolution.height,
  facingMode: "user",
};

const Cam = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const model = faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedModels.MediaPipeFaceMesh;
  const detectorConfig = {
    runtime: "mediapipe", // or 'tfjs'
    solutionPath: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh",
  };

  const runFacemesh = async () => {
    const detector = await faceLandmarksDetection.createDetector(
      model,
      detectorConfig
    );
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(detector);
    }, 10);
  };

  const detect = async (detector) => {
    if (
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null
    ) {
      // Get Video Properties
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      const videoWidth = webcamRef.current.video.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = webcamRef.current.video.videoHeight;

      // Set video width
      webcamRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
      webcamRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

      // Set canvas width
      canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
      canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;

      const face = await detector.estimateFaces({ input: video });
      console.log(face);

      // Get canvas context
      const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        drawMesh(face, ctx);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Not working!");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    runFacemesh();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Webcam
        ref={webcamRef}
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
      />
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        width={inputResolution.width}
        height={inputResolution.height}
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cam;
```

I use an aux function which draws the mesh:

```js
// Triangle drawing method
const drawPath = (ctx, points, closePath) => {
  const region = new Path2D();
  region.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    const point = points[i];
    region.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
  }
  if (closePath) {
    region.closePath();
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
  ctx.stroke(region);
};

// Drawing Mesh
export const drawMesh = (predictions, ctx) => {
  if (predictions.length > 0) {
    predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
      const keypoints = prediction.scaledMesh;

      //  Draw Triangles
      for (let i = 0; i < TRIANGULATION.length / 3; i++) {
        // Get sets of three keypoints for the triangle
        const points = [
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3],
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3 + 1],
          TRIANGULATION[i * 3 + 2],
        ].map((index) => keypoints[index]);
        //  Draw triangle
        drawPath(ctx, points, true);
      }

      // Draw Dots
      for (let i = 0; i < keypoints.length; i++) {
        const x = keypoints[i][0];
        const y = keypoints[i][1];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 1 /* radius */, 0, 3 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "aqua";
        ctx.fill();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

When I run the app locally I face an error that I've never faced:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Overload resolution failed.
    at pa.h (face_mesh.js:63:1)
    at sa (face_mesh.js:14:1)
    at ta.next (face_mesh.js:15:1)
    at g (face_mesh.js:42:1)
```

I don't know how to solve it so any piece of help is welcome! Thanks in advance!

I tried to remove the setInterval function call but the change had no effect at all...